# showing thai language from sqlserver in java swing

Tags: java, database, encoding

I am facing some problem by getting thai word from sql server 2000 database in java netbeans 7.1
i've made the connection using net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver and after making the connection when i want to read the table values (which are stored in thai language) say

> เพชรสี่เหลี่ยม

is the desired value to get in a message box (for example) instead my program shows

> à¾ªÃÊÕèàËÅÕèÂÁ

i am using jdk 1.7

here is my code snippet:

```
 PreparedStatement pre = null;

    try {
        pre = con.prepareStatement("select  * from setting");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewFrm1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        rs = pre.executeQuery();
         while(rs.next())
        {

            String strthai = rs.getString(3); \\ this is a varchar field in database

            ShowMessage( strthai,"coding");

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewFrm1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I've made this clear by making testing programs in both VB 6.0 and delphi 5 that those test programs are showing the correct thai words (ie เพชรสี่เหลี่ยม ) in their programs for the same table.

I am trying searching a lot and already spent 2 days to resolve this issue 
please give me some solution regarding this issue.

Comment: I am not very good with encoding and such, but I managed to find some details... The default JVM Encoding is UTF-8, which means your characters aren't gonna show up properly. You could try seeing if that's the problem by using `new String(rs.getString(3),"UTF-16")` and replace UTF-16 with the encoding you have to use. It could also be because of your Database collation, but since it's working in VB and Delphi then that's not as likely I think... I'm probably wrong on all of this but it's better than nothing! Good luck!

Comment: Take this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b1810b0f-d5f4-4b71-99a0-4510ae32e93c/view-source), but change the font to the one that fully supports many Unicode character sets like `Arial Unicode MS` which is provided by Microsoft Office installation. If you need to encode your String that contains Thai charset, do like this: `unicodeThaiMessage = new String(thaiString.getBytes(), "UTF-8");` If not UTF-8, change it to UTF-16

Comment: Dear PeekaySwitch & eee Thanks for your help, i've tried according to your suggestion first itried like this String strNew = new String(rs.getString(3).getBytes(),"UTF-8"); it gives me the same result i.e.  à¾ªÃÊÕèàËÅÕèÂÁ then i tried for String strNew = new String(rs.getString(3).getBytes(),"UTF-16"); it gives me 쎠슾슪쎃쎊쎕쎨쎠쎋쎅쎕쎨쎂쎁 and then i tried again for String strNew = new String(rs.getString(3).getBytes(),"TIS-620"); then only it gives me ร ยพยชร�ร�ร�รจร ร�ร�ร�รจร�ร� not a meaningful data while the string i tried เพชรสี่เหลี่ยม meaning in english is "Diamond Square".

Comment: Sincerely Thanks to both of you

Comment: Sincerely thanks to both of you PeekaySwitch and eee that you gave me some sort of idea that how to handle this scenario and after 1 hour of hectic try and try again in encoding a thai string i found following code to fulfill my task ie. String strNew = new String(rs.getString(3).getBytes("ISO8859_1"),"TIS-620"); thanks again for your cooperation.

Comment: Nice work irfan. As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Probably you won't be capable of answer yourself but when you do remember you can answer your own questions.